How to handle different needs and if conditions in reusable workflows?
I have multiple GitHub Actions jobs in my workflow, and most of the code is similar among them. To reduce code repetition, I want to create a reusable function and call it in each job. I referred to the GitHub documentation on reusing workflows, but I'm facing difficulty in handling different needs and if conditions for each job.
Here is an example of my GitHub Actions jobs:
 test-1:
    name: test-1
    strategy:
      matrix:
        shard: [1, 2, 3]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 10
    needs: [test-0]
    if: |
      always() && (needs.test-0.result == 'success')
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3.5.1
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'
      - name: Set Env variable
        env:
          HOST: ${{needs.test-0.outputs.UI_URL}}
        run: |
          echo "DB=${{ secrets.DB }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "HOST=$HOST" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install --prefix src/test-1/
      - name: Install Playwright
        run: cd src/test-1/; npx playwright@1.31.2 install chromium
      - name: Run Playwright
        run: cd src/test-1/ ; command="npx playwright test --shard=${{ matrix.shard }}/${{ strategy.job-total }} ./playwright/test-1"; $command || $command

  test-2:
    name: test-2
    strategy:
      matrix:
        shard: [1, 2, 3]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 10
    needs: [test-0]
    if: |
      always() && (needs.test-0.result == 'success')
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3.5.1
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'
      - name: Set Env variable
        env:
          HOST: ${{needs.test-0.outputs.UI_URL}}
        run: |
          echo "DB=${{ secrets.DB }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "HOST=$HOST" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install --prefix src/test-2/
      - name: Install Playwright
        run: cd src/test-2/; npx playwright@1.31.2 install chromium
      - name: Run Playwright
        run: cd src/test-2/ ; command="npx playwright test --shard=${{ matrix.shard }}/${{ strategy.job-total }} ./playwright/test-2"; $command || $command

  test-3:
    name: test-3
    strategy:
      matrix:
        shard: [1, 2, 3]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 10
    needs: [test-0, test-4]
    if: |
      always() && (needs.test-0.result == 'success') && (needs.test-4.result == 'success')
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3.5.1
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'
      - name: Set Env variable
        env:
          HOST: ${{needs.test-0.outputs.UI_URL}}
        run: |
          echo "DB=${{ secrets.DB }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "HOST=$HOST" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install --prefix src/test-3/
      - name: Install Playwright
        run: cd src/test-3/; npx playwright@1.31.2 install chromium
      - name: Run Playwright
        run: cd src/test-3/ ; command="npx playwright test --shard=${{ matrix.shard }}/${{ strategy.job-total }} ./playwright/test-3"; $command || $command

As you can see, each job has different needs and if conditions. How can I refactor this code to eliminate redundancy while still accommodating the varying conditions for each job?

Why don't you use a composite action, rather than a reusable workflow?

I feel a reusable function would be much easier. Also, I have never used a composite action. So I'll check it, but in the meantime, let's see if anyone can help with my queries
